# Remove onclick action on one of the TD in collapsible row

Tags: html, angular, html-table

I have implemented your angular2-collapsible, and it works well for the requirement (onclick of row, show details in collapsible manner).

I, however have one specific thing that I am trying to get it to work. I have a row that expands with further details in them onclick of the row (anywhere in row). Now, there is a drop down column in this row. Whenever I click this drop-down, to select some option from the drop-down, the whole row gets clicked and the whole row expands instead of just this column's drop-down expand.

How do I remove this expand property from this just one column, that has drop-down code (select drop-down).

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

This is the module I used.
https://dmitriiser.github.io/angular2-collapsible-example/

```
     <collapsible-table-row [detail]="detail">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test1, test2</td>
          <td>hjjg</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>tto</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>raw</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>date</td>
          <td (click)="tdclick()">
            <div>
              <select (click)="onClickofdd($event)" [(ngModel)]="nName" 
               name="nName" style="display:block;">
                <option value="">Option1</option>
                <option [ngValue]="postID">Optioin2</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
        </collapsible-table-row>
```

.ts file code below:

```
    tdclick($event){
    $event.stopPropagation();
  }

  onClickofdd(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Am able to trigger the clicks, but for some reason, the dropdown keeps closing automatically. am able to click on dropdown, but it doesn't stay open for me to select an option.

Update: Here's the code for what I have in HTML. According to latest version of angular2-collapsible, the click even should not be triggered if its not TR/TD. but now, when I click on select dropdown, the dropdown opens like for a blink of a second and closes.

```
   <div class="sampleclass">
    <h5 style="color: #008080;font-weight:bold">Table Data!</h5>
    <collapsible-table [type]="'accordion'" bordered="true" striped="true">
      <thead>
        <collapsible-table-row>
          <th>Test Name</th>
          <th>Test MTest </th>
          <th>Test </th>
          <th>Test </th>
          <th>Test </th>
        </collapsible-table-row>
      </thead>

      <tbody *ngFor="let tad of datatable">
        <collapsible-table-row [detail]="detail">
          <td>{{tad .test}}</td>
          <td>{{tad .firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{tad .testarea}}</td>
          <td>{{tad .testplay}}</td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <select>
                <option value="">please select an option</option>
                <option *ngFor="let kat of Types">{{kat.dropdownoption}}
    </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
        </collapsible-table-row>
        <collapsible-table-row-detail #detail centered="true">
          <div class="container" style="margin-bottom:25px;margin-left: 
    10%;width: 40%;">
            <p style="font-weight:bold;margin-top:25px;">Details: 
    {{tad.name}}</p>
            <hr style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
            <div class="right">
              {{tad.test}} <br>
             ////// expanded view
            </div>
          </div>
        </collapsible-table-row-detail>
      </tbody>
    </collapsible-table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a fix put in by the admin. Getting the latest PR from the module fixed the issue. 
Placing the Github convo for reference, if anyone needs help on this in future.
 [https://github.com/DmitriiSer/angular2-collapsible-example/issues/2][1]

Answer (score 0):

Try manually capturing the click event on the select element and stopping events bubbling with `event.stopPropagation`:

```
<select (click)=clickHandler($event)></select>

...

clickHandler(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

This should make event not trigger on parent elements, including your `row`.

If you really wan't to disable the row click, you could do it like this:

```
<row (click)="shouldRowBeClickableBoolean && clickHandlerFunction()"></row>
```

Comment: Hi @ritaj, I have tried the event.stopPropagation(); on this perticular TD and select tag as well. It disabled the click, but then the drop down is also disabled. I am then unable to click on the select dropdown. Any workaround for this? thank you, for your quick response on this.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have tried?

Comment: You can try this code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slddpq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have tried exactly what you suggested, posted the response in my question. Unable to select the option for some reason. (>.<)

Comment: So, I still have this issue. I have added the code in my quesiton.